# How do I make my navigation link have a box around it upon hover?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the odd title, didn't really know what to call it. 
I'm new to designing, as I generally stick to back-end but a friend suggested I give it a go. What I'm trying to do is get this

[image]

to look like this

[image]

My current css for it is as follows.

```css
#main-nav {
  margin-top:70px;
}

#main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main-nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

#main-nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing when it comes to designing and it may be an easy solution but I don't have the slightest idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your HTML as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `padding` and `border` to your CSS:

```
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #333;
```

The complete CSS you might need is:

```css
#main-nav a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited as question has changed. As others have said, you want to add padding to your a:hover.

```
#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` element needs `display: block` as well. You're adding a background to the `a` element, and by default that element is inline, meaning the height and width of the bounding box are determined by the contents. You will also need to add some padding.

```css
#main-nav {
  background: #000077;
}

#main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-nav a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#">What?</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that `display: block` is necessary, since otherwise the layout of the button will be dictated by the text contained in it rather than the width and height computed with the padding. If you add padding without modifying the `display` property, you will notice that the padding has an effect, but the `ul` and `li` size still according to the text rather than the computed width and height.

Check out the snippet below to see what I mean:

```css
#main-nav {
  background: #000077;
}

#main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-nav a {
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#">What?</a></li>
</ul>
```